# Custom module does not get its classes loaded

Tags: magento2, module

I'm trying to create a module for my Magento 2 installation because I need to change some behaviours.
I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776400/create-new-module-in-magento2-stable-version/33917874#33917874) to build a module which basically (at the moment) just wants to override a method for GroupManagement class in Customer Model. The matter is that when I run the setup:upgrade command everything seems to be ok, but then every request to the site gets an exception.
I looked into logs and found that my class is not found (there is a ReflectionException "class does not exist"). What it seems to me is that something is missing telling the autoloader to load my module's namespace. Should I manually update some autoloader.php file? I don't think that's intended as a solution, but what am I missing?

Comment: Very stupid question but... have you cleaned the cache? Are you running magento in `developer` mode? Also, have you tried to delete everything under `var/generation`?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned the cache and I deleted var/generation contents. I'm in default mode currently.

Comment: How are you trying to override/extend the method? Via plugin? Can you please specify your code structure?

Comment: No, I didn't use a plugin because it did not fit my needs.
I just have a class which extends GroupManagement, and a di.xml file that specifies to use this class as a Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface. And this seems to work, as long as Magento says it doesn't find my class. The matter is: how to get my module's class in autoloader?

Comment: Can you please post your project structure? If your code is under `app/code`, there is usually no need to edit the autoloader (for sure you shouldn't do it manually), as long as you follow class path conventions, e.g. `app/code/[Company]/[Module]/YourClass.php` for class `\[Company]\[Module]\YourClass`.

Comment: Well, my classes are under app/code/[Company]/[Module]/src/MyClass.php. That's slightly different from what you posted, but this is specified inside my module's composer.json, inside "psr-4" key under "autoload". Shouldn't that trigger something?
I actually got it to work manually adding a line to autoload_psr4.php, but as you wrote, I don't think that's the right way to do it.

Comment: Well, if you install your module via composer it would work as expected. The thing is: composer is not aware of your module if you place it under `app/code`. As an easy solution, you could edit the project `composer.json` and add your "psr-4" definition there, e.g. `"[Company]\\[Module]\\": "app/code/[Company]/[Module]/src/"` and after that simply run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Or even better, if possible, skip the `src/` folder and simply follow Magento convention.

Comment: @fmrng I tried the last way, skipping src folder, but again I get ReflectionException as my classes are not found. By the way, in which way is Magento supposed to know about my classes being there, if nothing is telling him?

Comment: and what is `composer dump-autoload` supposed to do?

Comment: Look at the project `composer.json`, Magento added a `psr-0` autoload definition `"": "app/code/"`, which is how the autoloader knows how to locate your classes. Again, for it to work correctly you have to stick to the `psr-0` convention, OR declare your own `psr-4` definition and trigger `composer dump-autoload`. This will regenerate the `vendor/autoload.php` and all its related files. I tried to do the very same you suggested and it worked, I guess the filepath is simply not correct.

Comment: Nothing... tried as you say, it doesn't work. Looks like my module's `composer.json` is not read at all. The only way I can get it to work is manually adding a line to `autoload_psr4.php`

Comment: Like I said, it's fine if you edit your module `composer.json`, it will work if you distribute your module or install it via composer. For "local" modules the `composer.json` will be ignored. Try to add your `psr-4` definition to the *project* `composer.json` (the one that is found in the project root), and then dump the autoload.

Comment: Fine.. I had not understand you intended editing the global `composer.json`. Now it actually works! Thank you very much @fmrng

Comment: I added an answer to sum up the solution, mark it as correct if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments I gather your module is being developed under `app/code` and you are not following `psr-0` conventions for your classes (code is under a custom `src` folder inside of your module). This is fine, but still, since composer is not aware of modules installed under `app/code`, it won't know about your `psr-4` definitions.

As a workaround for that, you could enter your `psr-4` classpaths in the **project** `composer.json` (the one which is found in the project root), and then run `composer dump-autoload` to regenerate the `vendor/autoload.php` and all its related files. Even if it is not the cleanest solution, it would still work in your case.

But **very important** to note: your should **never** manually edit the autoloader files, since they are re-generated every time you install a new module via composer for example. Also, you probably don't want to put your `vendor` folder under version control, your edits would be lost then.

Comment: Sorry for seeing your answer just now. Anyway I had tried without `src` folder too, and classes were not found as I wrote in my comment on Apr 27 at 16.49 CET. Maybe I'm wrong, but what I see is that Magento can automatically detect classes that are directly placed under `app/code`, and not under `app/code/<vendor>/<module>`. So I didn't find a solution other than editing the project `composer.json` and regenerate autoload files.
Thanks for your help, anyway!

Comment: I do have a composer.json in my module root, in which I define an additional PSR-4 namespace, but it does not get picked up on regenrating the autoload classes. Thus: my classes that obey the Magento 2 structure are found, but an additional library (code commoon to a number of extensions for different webshops) that comes with it, is not found.

Comment: Maybe enter a new question, and post your code. I can try to help you... From a comment it's hard to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple reasons but below could be among them...

**1. Check the name space of your classes..**

**2. give the permission of your Magento directory according to the official document.**

[magento official document for permission set](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html)

**3. And obviously all the classes should start with uppercase with same file name.**

**4. Classes should not contain UNDERSCORE(_)**.

Hope this will help, please let me know if issue still persist...

Comment: Thanks for answering, but all the points you stated seem to be ok. I guess the matter is I need something to put my module's namespace in autoload. How can I get it?

Comment: you don't need to put anything in autoloader.php, We are not suppose to make any changes there. May be I can help you better if I can see your codes along with directory path..

Comment: Please take a look at my comment above (6th comment to the question), thanks!

Comment: Thanks @mohammad-mujassam. `Classes should not contain UNDERSCORE(_)` helped me